# Windows 7: Comments in Windows Explorer only for certain file types?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, comments

I tried using the comments feature in Windows Explorer in Windows 7, but I only get the option to add a comment only for certain file types like photos.

Is it possible to add comments to other files that I work on like Photoshop files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments feature watermarks (changes) the actual data in the file, rather than adding meta data in the file system.  So you can only add comments on file types like jpeg or mp3 that can handle watermarking.

Comment: but its possible to add comments on other file types in Windows XP so why is this feature disabled in Windows 7

Answer (score 1):

I believe that Explorer is simply providing an interface to the metadata fields inherent in some file types (e.g. ID3v2 tags on MP3s and EXIF fields in JPEGs and some other image formats).

Some other systems, such as the Nepomuk/Soprano stack in KDE keep a database of file references and metadata associated with that file, and so they allow arbitrary metadata to be associated with any file (although it is only visible via programs that are Nepomuk/Soprano aware and on that system). I don't know if any Windows or Mac software (i.e. Google Desktop Search) supports this.